# Why not all consumers are properly revoked before assigning new partitions within singe group

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Consider there are 4 consumers (A,B,C,D) . C is closed by calling close(). Ideally Partitions assigned to A,B and D should be revoked before assigning any new partitions but A is getting revoked and getting new partitions and then B is getting revoked. Why this behaviour is observed ? How can this be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka 2.4 a new incremental rebalancing protocol was added, that does not revoke all partitions during a rebalance: https://www.confluent.io/blog/cooperative-rebalancing-in-kafka-streams-consumer-ksqldb/